# ASP.net MVC Controller Taking a FormCollection AND an Integer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, parameters

I have a simple form, a text box and a command button. I am using a method="post" to get the value which is entered into the textbox to the controller. The controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
        {
```

This is all fine, but later down the line I want to be able to use the following:             return RedirectToAction("../MyFolder/MyView/" + MyID); but because my initial view (Index) worked by passing a form collection, I cannot do the above. How can I make this possible? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can hardly make any sense out of your question but here's a commonly used pattern in ASP.NET MVC which you might be helpful:

```
// Used to render some form allowing to edit a model
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var model = _someRepository.Get(id);
    return View(model);
}

// used to handle the submission of the form
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model was invalid => redisplay the form insulting the user
        return View(model);
    }
    // TODO: the user entered valid information => process the model
    // and redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.Id });
}
```

Comment: I tried the following code snippet, and I have this code to try to Redirect to a method. return RedirectToAction("../MyFolder/Index/" + ID); When I place a breakpoint here I have a value inside ID.. when it runs, it goes into  public ActionResult Index(int id) { but it says the id is null.. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cal, did you notice the way I am using the `RedirectToAction` method in my answer? Like this `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = ID })` and not `return RedirectToAction("../MyFolder/Index" + ID })`. You also have an overload which takes a controller name if different than the current controller.

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question, you can rewrite your method as

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, FormCollection forms)
    {...}
```

Than you can use both `forms` and `id`